# How do i write the following in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I am using `dotnetcore 3.1` to develop my `WebAPI` and I have a query like this:

```
string sql = 
String.Format(
@"SELECT    u.Id as id,
    Email as email,
    u.name as name,
    lastname,
    PhoneNumber as phoneNumber,
    r.name as role 
FROM table1 u 
inner join table2 userRole 
   on userRole.UserId = u.id 
inner join table3 r 
   on r.Id = userRole.RoleId 
where Email='{0}'", email);
```

Previously I was using Raw SQL to get my data as follows:
`userList = _dbContext.User.FromSqlRaw(sql).SingleOrDefault();`

Now I want to use `EF's Complex Querying structure` to create the above SQL as suggested by Other devs here.
So far I have gotten this but I am getting errors:

```
var query = (   from u in _dbContext.User
                join userRoles in _dbContext.UsersRoles on u.id equals 
                userRoles.UserId
                join r in _dbContext.Role on r.id equals userRoles.RoleId
                where u.email == username
             select u);
```

Please advice.

### Update My bad I totally forgot to mention the error [Smiley face with tears]

`join r in _dbContext.Role on r.id equals userRoles.RoleId`
Getting error on above line:
`The name 'r' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'`

### Update:

The reason I am using EF is because of issue related to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635268/how-to-insert-in-a-string-in-c).
I was able to fix the issue in the `Login Controller` but there are other `Controllers` which are using the email and my email address contains special characters which are generating errors on `Mysql` side because of some of those characters when passed using Raw SQL.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Ah yes, the infamous `errors`. Perhaps it would be useful to actually add those to the question?

Comment: try changing  it to `userRoles.RoleId equals r.id`

Comment: Did that still getting the same error.

Comment: You're probably really close.  This is probably an issue with using ".Id" as surrogatekey for things, instead of "User.UserId" as surrogate key.  All the "Id's" are ambiguous and get confusing.  I actually prefer "User.UserKey", "Role.RoleKey" as an alternative to "Id" suffixes on everything.  Why?  is an "EmployeeId"...the surrogate key on a the database table OR is EmployeeId the id-an-employee-gets that they show on their badge? (and has nothing to do with a database)?  Ambiguity causes too many bugs and development-time issues that its worth IMHO.

Comment: As an in general debugging tip, if you figure out how to attach the logging/logger to the dbcontext, you can "see" the generated sql, which can really help in debugging scenarios.  See https://github.com/granadacoder/oracle-ef-issues-demo/blob/master/src/DataLayer.EntityFramework/Contexts/EfPlaygroundDbContext.cs#L66

Comment: Nitpick.  Since the property is something like Dbset<User>, (note the "set" which means more than one).......most use this for naming convention.  dbContext public DbSet<User> Users {get;set}      (note the pluralized Users).  Its a mini holy war..but just pointing out what most do.

Comment: If the previous was working in sending raw sql, what is gained by switching?

Comment: [equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#the-equals-operator) wants the operands in a particular order, unlike sql

Comment: You can [pass parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#passing-parameters) using FromSqlRaw. Do not include values in the command string itself.